# Error in loading mainline kernel

Tags: kernel, 20.04

I am trying to upgrade from kernel 5.4.0-51-generic to 5.8 and I am facing an error when rebooting. The error says that

```
error: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.1...-generic has invalid signature
error: need to load the kernel
```

how should i activate it before rebooting? or fix the problem somehow? I can access previous kernel in ubuntu by the recovery mode.

Answer (score 4):

Disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings. Mainline kernels are unsigned and incompatible with Secure Boot.

Comment: it worked, thank you very much :)